# Can we add multiple InApp purchase in one time?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Can we add multiple InApp purchase in one time? 
Because I have 15 InApp purchase items and i have to add those 15 InApp purchase in more than 12 Application.

so I asking you for any idea that create multiple InApp purchase in one time?

Comment: Are you referring to adding them in iTunes connect? Or handling them in you code?

Answer (score 0):

No, There is no other way. You should add all of them manually.